# How to use Let's Encrypt with both EC2 and Cloudfront?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, lets-encrypt, amazon-cloudfront, aws-cli

I want to use Let's Encrypt certificates for both EC2 and Cloudfront.

- I am creating a wordpress installation EC2 t2.micro using Ubuntu
  16.04(HVM) AMI and nginx. EC2 region will be us-east-2 (Ohio).
- I can create Let's Encrypt cert using the certbot for the EC2 and can
  upload the cert to AWS IAM through CLI to use for Cloudfront.

The issue I am facing is:
The certificate generated by certbot for the EC2 will be for ***example.com*** but I want to use ***cdn.example.com*** for Cloudfront. Is it possible to create and use two different certs, one for the EC2 and the other for Cloudfront?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [AWS Certificate Manager](https://aws.amazon.com/certificate-manager/) to create the cert for CloudFront. Use Let's Encrypt for the instance security certificate.

I've done this, it works fine.

Comment: The issue is I will be using US-east-2 as the region for my EC2 and ACM for Cloudfront is available for us-east-1 (N. Virginia)

Comment: I ran my server and other resources on Oregon, us-west-2 I think it is. From memory you just issue the certificate in us-east-1 and use it in whatever region you need.

Comment: This is correct... CloudFront is not like most AWS services -- it is a global, not regional, service... and the control plane for its global infrastructure happens to be homed out of us-east-1, thus it can only pull certs from ACM in us-east-1.  There's no performance impact to this, just an administrative constraint.